# Why force $F$ is equal to $ma$ and not $mv$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, mass, acceleration, velocity

I was confused with this equation like why force is equal to $ma$ and not $mv$? Then I read the same question here on stack exchange, it's answers almost made sense but I still can't visualise the situation where a thing is moving at a constant velocity, would it then have no force? But if I think this scenario in my head, it would definitely have force when it hit something. So I wonder if I am mis-associating the terms in the equation?

Comment: @VivekMittal...No force for constant velocity (which would keep in moving on a frictionless plane )

Comment: Which other stack exchange question?

Answer (score 4):

> I was confused with this equation like why force is equal to ma and not mv?

Think of it like this:

- Sometimes stuff accelerates. Such an acceleration might have a *cause*. Let's name that cause: **force**.
- And we might notice that stuff that feels "heavier", accelerates less. Throwing a ball and a concrete block equally much shows this. Some stuff is "tougher" to accelerate. Let's name that "resistance against acceleration": **mass**.

(Actually, in general this "resistance against acceleration" is called **inertia**. For linear (translational) motion we call that inertia **mass**.)

> a thing is moving at a constant velocity, would it then have no force?

Correct. No force when velocity is constant.

Think of a drifting spaceship. It has rockets to push it forward and accelerate (the rocket force causes acceleration). But then they are turned off. What happens now?  Does the spaceship stop? Does it brake?

No, it just continues. The velocity it has when it stops acceleration just remains. The spaceship drifts at this speed forever through space until reaching something new that causes acceleration.

> But if I think this scenario in my head, it would definitely have force when it hit something.

Yes, definitely, because when it hits something, **it is abruptly slowed down**. That is a **huge acceleration** (or deceleration, if you will).

The key issue here is to realize that:

- Force is **not something an object "has"**. An object does not "carry" force along with it.
- Force is only something an object can **do**! Force is only about **interactions**; only about contact with *another* object (or field or alike).

You can say that an object carries **momentum**. That is: $p=mv$. This momentum contains both the speed $v$ an object has as well as its "toughness" against being slowed down, the mass $m$. And when the object hits something, momentum is transferred. This change in momentum (and how fast it is changed) **is force**.

Force is the interacting; the "thing" that causes acceleration or transfers the momentum during collisions.

> So I wonder if I am mis-associating the terms in the equation? Sorry for my bad english.

No worries, sir. We are many non-native English speakers here.

Answer (score 1):

Re. f = ma:

Its the force that's being applied to the 'thing', and the resulting acceleration of the 'thing', and the 'things' mass.

It is not the 'things' force (which is related to its momentum, mv).  If it is moving with constant velocity, then no force is being applied to it.

Answer (score 1):

Besides dimension, we don't use $F=mv$, because it is the *wrong* physics law - it predicts incorrectly.

The $F=mv$ is pretty much just the physics law of motion *before* Galileo - a law says the natural state of all things is *at rest*; simple moving in constant speed requires external force. However, it is simply wrong - what the natural state of things is *at uniform motion* (as in outer space, a spaceship needs *nothing* to move). If a net force is acted on the object, then it will accelerate (while the wrong physic law says a constant force will only bring the object to move in a constant speed).

Answer (score 0):

I could, technically speaking, respond to you with something trivial like "force is defined as being that which mediates a change in momentum", but that feels insubstantial for you.

Mass times velocity gives the momentum of an object. Mass times acceleration gives the force imparted on it. An object with uniform velocity has no net force acting on it. If it hits something, there is a net force because now the object is accelerating (or rather, decelerating).

Force does not describe the potential for something to accelerate another object, it describes how much an object of a certain mass is itself accelerating. Got a $3kg$ object that's experiencing 2-g's of acceleration? Then something must be applying a force of around $60N$ to it.

Instead of always listing the masses and accelerations of everything in a system, we physicists found it to be far easier to multiply those numbers together and call that "force" (okay, it's a tad more complicated). Force isn't a property an object carries, it's a description of a change that is happening to an object. If nothing changes about it, there's no net force on it.

Answer (score 0):

If an object is moving at a constant velocity, then it is true there is no force. But consider your question about the contact you feel from the object that is moving at constant velocity and proceeds to hit your head. In this case, you are dealing with the impulse: the change in the objects momentum. When the object comes into contact with you, it is no longer maintaining its constant velocity and it undergoes a change in momentum, which if occurs rather quickly is painfully exchanged to your head. Now we know that force is simply the time derivative of the momentum, so

(change in momentum / change in time) = Average Force

that is the force you feel hitting you that is no longer a result of an object moving at constant velocity, but rather accelerating due to a collision.

Just an edit to give some more detail:

Notice how in the above equation, if the collision occurs in a very short amount of time, then you are dividing by a very small number and so the force you feel will be very large, hence the "pain"

Now if you keep the same change in momentum, but cushion the collision with a pad so that the change in momentum takes longer, you are dividing by a bigger number, effectively reducing the force you feel.

Answer (score 0):

To move a real thing on earth with constant velocity, you usually do need a constant force because you have to overcome *friction*.

In an idealized frictionless setting, a moving thing keeps moving forever, in the same direction and with the same speed, if no force is acting on it.

In this frictionless setting, the acceleration of a body is proportional to the (sum of) forces acting on the body with the mass of the body as the coefficient of proportionality. If a body has a greater mass than another, you need a greater force to get the same acceleration.