# Why isn't force $\vec{F}=m \vec{v}$ instead of $\vec{F}=m \vec{a}$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

Why isn't force $F=m\vec v$ instead of $F=m\vec a$?

If I'm standing in a wind that's blowing at a steady 100 mph, would that not impart a force on me?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion

Comment: The "a" refers to the acceleration of the body, not the object providing the force. Thus, even if you use "v" instead, that would be your velocity, not the wind's.

Comment: Ahh I see. The formula is for the object being moved and not for the thing actually causing the movement.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why force $F$ is equal to $ma$ and not $mv$?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/388869/)

Comment: Come on you all. Look for dupes first

Answer (score 2):

> If I'm standing in a wind that's blowing at a steady 100 mph, would that not impart a force on me?

Yes, it would impart a force on you. But it won't be because the wind is moving at 100 mph. It will be because the air molecules going 100 mph *slow down or stop (or change direction)* when they hit you.

This change in velocity of the molecules (wrt time) is what we call the acceleration of the molecules. And your body imparts a force on them.

Just to clarify, the molecules also impart a force on you, but the friction of the floor will probably cancel this force out. So your velocity does not change.

Comment: Thank you. I understand. Conservation of momentum. The air molecules would be transferring there momentum to me.

Answer (score 2):

> If I'm standing in a wind that's blowing at a steady 100 mph, would that not impart a force on me?

Of course it would. That force is known to vehicle and aircraft designers as [*parasitic drag*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parasitic_drag). But FYI, *that* force does not depend on the mass of anything, and it is not *directly* proportional to the wind speed.

$\vec{F}=m\vec{a}$ alright, but you have to know what $\vec{F}$, $m$, and $\vec{a}$ stand for in order to properly apply that law. It's not as simple as "force" and "mass" and "acceleration:" It's the *net force* acting on a [*free body*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_body), and it's the mass and the acceleration of *the same* free body, and they all must be expressed in a [*consistent system of measurement*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_measurement), and in the [*same coordinate system*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_system). It's only when you get all of those details right, that the $\vec{F}=m\vec{a}$ law expresses an absolute truth.

Answer (score 1):

Both quantities, $m \vec a$ and $m \vec v$, are important quantities in physics. In general, important quantities get names, so it is not surprising that both of these quantities should be named: force and momentum respectively.

However, there is no particular reason that a given quantity has a specific name. That is really unimportant. Everyone has agreed to use the word “force” to refer to $m\vec a$ and the word “momentum” to refer to $m \vec v$, and though it didn’t have to be that way that is the way it is.

So, to directly answer your question, force isn’t $m\vec v$ because the physics community decided to use that word for $m\vec a$.

Answer (score 1):

$F=ma$ is always true (in non-relativistic classical physics), for all forces.

Your example, wind force, is called drag force. The formulation is usually as:

$$ F_{\rm drag} = C_DA\rho v^2 $$

where $C_D$ is the coefficient of drag (which depends on several factors), $A$ is the cross-sectional area you present to the wind, $\rho$ is the air density, and $v$ is the speed...of the wind.

You may ask, what happened to $m$?...well drag force does not depend on *your* mass, but your acceleration does, through F=ma:

$$ a = F_{\rm drag}/m $$

There is another mass, though:

$$ A\rho v $$

is area times density time length per unit time, it is the rate at which mass is striking you.

You pick up another factor of $v$ because it is the rate at which you must accelerate this mass to 0, which is another manifestation of the ubiquitous:

$$ F = MA$$

Answer (score 0):

Force is defined as the first derivative of momentum with respect to time, hence why we have $\vec{F} = m \frac{d \vec{v}}{dt}$. Therefore, the distinction between momentum and force is that force yields a *change* in velocity.

Comment: This isn't quite correct. Wind at constant velocity will certainly exert a force upon you if you're standing in its way, until you reach its velocity.

Comment: That is very true, I didn’t even think of that! How do you suggest I edit my answer? @TheEnvironmentalist

Comment: I think the core insight the OP is missing in the question is the idea that a force doesn't _give you a velocity_, it gives you a _change in your velocity_, which perfectly corresponds to the difference between momentum and velocity. Find a solid intuitive explanation for that and you've got yourself a real winner :)

Comment: @TheEnvironmentalist - Sounds great, I will think of an explanation along those lines. Thank you for such great feedback!

Comment: Thanks for asking! It's a rare treat to find people as open to critique and feedback. More people like you make for a stronger community

Comment: @TheEnvironmentalist - Of course! I’m a mathematician by practice and profession, so I thrive off of critique. I do hope to contribute more to the physics community as my graduate studies progress :-).

Comment: @TheEnvironmentalist Wind at a constant velocity will not exert a force on you because it will not hit you. The air that does hit you will indeed change velocity, as it’s momentum is transferred to you. This answer is technically correct, if not exactly illuminating.

Comment: @Gilbert how does a wind with a constant velocity not hit you?

Comment: @Aneikei the point is that a wind that hits you has, practically by definition, a non-constant velocity. Therefore, if the wind velocity is constant, then you must be elsewhere.